# Visual Basic Help - Text limitations in a visual basic text box to prevent certain characters being entered

Tags: vb.net

This is a simple thing that I have been trying to figure out for a while now and its starting to annoy. All I want to is when a button is pressed only certain values are allowed to appear in the textbox. What is meant by this is for example only allow "abc123!" in the textbox and if say a value such as "w" then clear the textbox.

I have tried things such as 'If Not Regex.Match' but it is just causing me errors.

Please help ;)

Comment: I actually need all characters a-z A-z 0-9 and all symbols to work, I would like to prevent characters such as 文 or any other language.

Comment: you need to write code on key events and verify if the key pressed is valid key. Basically you need to fortify all events where data being typed or pasted into your text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a white list.  Your allowed characters would be a much smaller list than every other character in existence.  You can do this a few ways.  You can handle the key press event on the text box and if that value is whatever, then you execute your code.  The other way you can do this (say if it was a winforms app) would be to inherit from the textbox and put your code there (you could re-use this control then).  Here is an example of a TextBox that only allows numeric input:

```
''' <summary>
''' Text box that only accepts numeric values.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class NumericTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private Const ES_NUMBER As Integer = &H2000

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim params As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            params.Style = params.Style Or ES_NUMBER
            Return params
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        'Prevent pasting of non-numeric characters
        If keyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Insert) OrElse keyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.V) Then
            Dim data As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject
            If data Is Nothing Then
                Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
            Else
                Dim text As String = CStr(data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, True))
                If text = String.Empty Then
                    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
                Else
                    For Each ch As Char In text.ToCharArray
                        If Not Char.IsNumber(ch) Then
                            Return True
                        End If
                    Next
                    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf keyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.A) Then
            ' Process the select all
            Me.SelectAll()
        Else
            Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

If you just want to use a TextBox and a KeyPress event you can do something like this.  I only have two characters in my white list, you'd want to include the characters for everything you'd want included:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    ' Test white list, this is only 0 and 1 which are ASCII 48 and 49
    Dim allowedChars() As String = {Chr(48), Chr(49)}

    If allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then
        ' Setting handled to true stops the character from being entered, remove this or execute your code
        ' here that you want
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

If you want a list of the char codes you can get them here:

http://www.asciitable.com/

Hope this helps. ;-)